# adding subviews in uiviewcontroller make it goes will

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I have a custom `UIView` that I need to add as a subview in a `UIViewController`.

But if I use `[self.view addSubview:newView];` the app goes in a infinity loop and doesn't start. But if I use `self.view = newView` then it works. But I need it as a subview.

The `UIView` contains a grid layout of custom button.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you do that in the `loadView` method. You must not call the `view` method of the view controller in `loadView` because that will itself call `loadView`! However calling `setView:` (e.g. `self.view = newView`) is okay.

My suggestion is to add the subview in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I have it in the 'viewDidLoad' and still looping.

Comment: It isn't more than :     NewsView *newsView = [[NewsView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 600, 800)]; [self.view addSubview:newsView]; Or self.view = newsView;